# EntityFramework context return empty rowset from db views

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have an application that uses Entity Framework to handle the database. The database consists of both tables and views.
One of the views is called FailedRecipient and is created with a where clause and some joins to other tables. In my repository class I have a method to collect all rows in the FailedRecipients view.

```
public IEnumerable<FailedRecipient> GetFailedRecipients()
        {
            return _context.FailedRecipients;
        }
```

But the result is zero row set. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.
Of course I have checked that the table actually contains any rows.

Comment: Count is 0 or object is null ?

Comment: Count is 0 @Ofiris. I updated my question too

Comment: Does the view have proper primary key properties in the EF context?

Comment: The view does not have any primary keys in the database, so I guess it doesn't have any in the EF context either. @GertArnold

Comment: Well, it should. EF also wants to track objects from views. It needs an identification to be able to do that. So you have to investigate by which columns the view rows are uniquely identified and mark these as primary key in the EF model.

Comment: But it is not possible to create primary keys on views? So I have to do this in the EF model, right? @GertArnold

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. That's the first step. Usually when no proper PK is defined EF will return *too many* rows, but still, it's the first thing to get right and then see how you get along.

Comment: I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd163156%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tutorial, but is there any way I can do this using the designer? @GertArnold

Comment: Sure, it's in the context menu of a property in the designer diagram.

Comment: Ok, I set the RecipientId in the view to be the primary key, but I still get the same result.

Comment: Look at the Sql query EF generates for your Linq query (e.g. use `.ToString()` or `.ToTraceString()` on the query). This should give you an insight if EF does the right thing and if it does why you don't receive any records. Or maybe you are using CodeFirst and EF created a new database which is empty?